# Eclipselink and Spring 3.1

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have got Hibernate working but I am trying to change to Eclipselink. I have been searching for a solution for this but without result. People suggest putting these two(not together)

```
<class>no.mesta.driftslogg.model.Person</class>  
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

in persistence.xml

---

persitence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="cccPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

---

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



<!-- Spring transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<!-- JPA Hibernate shared entity manager -->
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" /


<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cccPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <!-- <property name="showSql" value="true" /> -->
</bean>



<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/driftslogg" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
</bean>
```

---

Dao class

```
package no.mesta.driftslogg.dao.jpa;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import no.mesta.driftslogg.dao.PersonDao;
import no.mesta.driftslogg.model.Person;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class PersonDaoJpa implements PersonDao {

protected EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Override
public Person save(Person person) {
    if (person.getId() != null) {
        return entityManager.merge(person);
    } else {
        entityManager.persist(person);
    }
    return person;
}

}
```

---

The entity class

```
package no.mesta.driftslogg.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

---

The error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Todo [summary=This is a test, description=This is a test] is not a known entity type.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Todo [summary=This is a test, description=This is a test] is not a known entity type.
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4169)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:440)
    no.mesta.driftslogg.dao.jpa.PersonDaoJpa.save(PersonDaoJpa.java:45)
    no.mesta.driftslogg.service.impl.PersonServiceImpl.savePerson(PersonServiceImpl.java:20)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy15.savePerson(Unknown Source)
    no.mesta.driftslogg.controller.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:31)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is on a "Todo" object, not a person.  Ensure you have mapped all of the related objects.

You need to put the no.mesta.driftslogg.model.Person in your persistence.xml, you do not have this.

Comment: Well sorry for the Todo. Person gives the same result. I was trying different entities. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the SimpleLoadTimeWeaver (I couldn't get that to work either), I use

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

That requires the use of the java agent from spring-instrument, so you will have to start the JVM with an agument telling it where to find that. Something like

```
-javaagent:spring-instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
```